# a second click to close a toggle div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using the following jQuery for hiding and showing content (toggle), as a tree navigation menu in my website. I found this code extremely useful because by clicking, it displays only one div at a time.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_region(chosen_region) {
     $('.city_div').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == chosen_region) {
               $(this).slideDown(200);
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }  
     });
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
   .city_div {display: none;}
</style>


<a href="javascript:show_region('box01');">North</a><br>
<div class="city_div" id="box01">Div #01</div>

<a href="javascript:show_region('box02');">Centre</a><br>
<div class="city_div" id="box02">Div #02</div>

<a href="javascript:show_region('box03');">South</a><br>
<div class="city_div" id="box03">Div #03</div>
```

The problem is that I can close a div only by opening another div.

How to close the div by a second click on it?

Comment: i think the right code for the a tags is `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show_region('box01');">North</a>`

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano: Take out the `javascript:`, though.

Comment: yep, you're right. So `<a href="#" onclick="show_region('box01');">North</a>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `slideToggle`, change from `slideDown` to `slideToggle`:

```
function show_region(chosen_region) {
     $('.city_div').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == chosen_region) {
               $(this).slideToggle(200); // instead of slideDown
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }  
     });
}
```

Comment: yep :) .. almost .. modified with your suggestion

Comment: Many thanks you all for your professional assistance.
I found that @ Mihai Iorga is a simple and a working solution for me (using slideToggle instead of slideDown).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use inline event handlers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var boxes = $('.city_div');

    $('.city-toggle').click(function(e) {
        var box = $(this).next();
        var isHidden = box.is(':hidden');

        boxes.slideUp(600);

        if(isHidden) {
            box.slideDown(200);
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
   .city_div {display: none;}
</style>


<a href="something-meaningful-like-north.html" class="city-toggle">North</a>
<div class="city_div" id="box01">Div #01</div>

<a href="ditto.html" class="city-toggle">Centre</a>
<div class="city_div" id="box02">Div #02</div>

<a href="same.html" class="city-toggle">South</a>
<div class="city_div" id="box03">Div #03</div>
```

Also, if your links don't go anywhere meaningful, use `#` as the `href` and make sure the boxes are visible by default. (Hide them using `boxes.hide();` right at the start.)

Also also, `<br>` isn't what you should use there. `<div>`s are already block-level elements. If you want more padding, give them a top margin.

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano: Oops, thanks - I didn't even notice that. Should be CSS.

Comment: you should use `e.preventDefault();` for the link click events

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a variable with your old chosen region name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var old_chosen_region="";
    function show_region(chosen_region) {
        $('.city_div').each(function(index) {
            if (($(this).attr("id") == chosen_region)&&(chosen_region!=old_chosen_region)) {
                $(this).slideDown(200);
                old_chosen_region=chosen_region;
            } else {
                $(this).slideUp(600);
            }
        }
        old_chosen_region='';
    });
</script>
```

This allows you to 'remember' which region you chose last and, if the *chosen one* equals the last you close it.

You should set  `old_chosen_region=''` in the end to let the tab reopen.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.city_div').click(function(){
        $(this).hide(); //or whatever code you want to hide it
    });
});
```

that way when you click on a div, it will hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery you could try using the [jQuery.toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

```
function show_region(chosen_region) {
     $('#' + chosen_region).toggle('slide');
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you using such an old version of jQuery?

Second, your JavaScript can be simplified. jQuery works on sets; you don't need the `.each`, or loops.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/25P9z/

Simplified HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-contentDiv="box01">North</a><br>
<div class="city_div" id="box01">Div #01</div>

<a href="#" data-contentDiv="box02">Centre</a><br>
<div class="city_div" id="box02">Div #02</div>

<a href="#" data-contentDiv="box03">South</a><br>
<div class="city_div" id="box03">Div #03</div>​
```

New JavaScript:

```
function show_region(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    var chosen_region = $target.attr('data-contentDiv');

    var openDiv = $('#' + chosen_region);

    openDiv.slideDown(200);
    $('.city_div').not(openDiv).slideUp(600);
}
```

Last, attach events, don't inline them in your HTML.

```
$('a[data-contentDiv]').click(show_region);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the div you have clicked last:

```
var globalLastClickedButtonId;
$("div.city_div").click(function() {
    if (globalLastClickedButtonId == $(this).attr("id")) {
        $(this).hide();
    } else {
        var box = $(this).next().next();
        var clickedId = $(this).attr("id");
        $("div.city_div").each(function() {
           if ($(this).attr("id") == clickedId)
              box.slideDown(200);
           else
              box.slideUp(600);
        }
    }
    globalLastClickedButtonId = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an animation it is best to keep track of the div that is currently shown. If you don't, then you will start to see multiple divs showing if you click links in quick succession.

You can use this:

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedDiv = $("#" + $(this).attr("href"));
        var hide = selectedDiv.data("shown");

        $(".city_div").slideUp(600);
        $(".city_div").data("shown", false);

        if (hide) {
            selectedDiv.data("shown", false);
        }
        else {
            selectedDiv.data("shown", true);
            selectedDiv.slideDown(200);
        }
    });
});​
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/kJ4qP/3/)

Comment: You can just check if it's visible using `.is(':visible')` instead of setting a `shown` data item.

Comment: @minitech: hmmm, I expected checking the visible flag not to work until the animation is complete, but it appears that it is fine with testing